# What's the meaning of 稿件投诉, I saw it on 哔哩哔哩 while streaming?

Tags: translation, meaning, vocabulary, phrase

While I stream videos on 哔哩哔哩, I saw `稿件投诉`. But when I searched on Pleco, `稿件` means `contribution` or `manuscript`, and `投诉` means `appeal` or `complain`. If we combine them both, what does it means? `Contribution complain`? Is it like `举报` or something? Please explain as detail as you can...

thankyou.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original meaning of 稿/稿件 is contribution/manuscript/draft/sketch as has been yielded by your search. It was a reference to a manuscript you submit (that is, a contribution you make) to editors of a magazine, newspaper, etc. back in the day when mass media mostly came in the form of paper.

In the context of Bilibili, 稿件 means a contribution you make to the platform, i.e. the video that you upload (*contribute*) onto it. A video is contrived, implemented and submitted to a video hosting platform just like a manuscript is to an editorial board, hence the extension of the meaning. Note that *submit* is 投稿 (投: to give out, send, deliver, or submit).

投诉 is more straightforward. It is the same as 举报. Therefore, 稿件投诉 means 举报视频 (report *this* video).

Comment: So, is 投稿 more like 上报?

Comment: You don't have to ask a question if you don't intend to.

Comment: Well, of course I ask because I intend to, what's wrong with you? I prefer your previous second answer rather than the edited one. But thanks for the first one. If you don't want to answer it, you don't have to be rude, I can also pass to another respondent in this community, regards.

Comment: And remember, this is a community where people discuss about mandarin one another to learn together, that is the purpose, mark those words, thankyou.

Comment: Sorry for being rude. 投稿 is to upload (a video), while 上报 is to report something (to the authority). The latter suggests modesty and obedience, and is usually used in such ways as 上报情况 (report the ins and outs / state of affairs) or 上报领导 (report to the leader).

Comment: Nevermind, thankyou, very clear and detail, and good english, 多感谢您的答案。

Answer (score 2):

稿件 means the video since most videos there are contributions uploaded by users.

投诉 means to file a complain. It is similar to 举报 but 举报 is more like "to report"

Answer (score 1):

学习汉语，要学会正确地增加一些东西，特别是对那些短语。

"稿件投诉",用稿件来投诉，这个短语的重点是投诉两个字。投诉和举报的意思差太大了，投诉是反应问题，不严重的，举报一定是严重的事情。

Comment: It is not 用稿件来投诉, but that you can make a complaint about that 稿件, which include but are not limited to video. That Bilibili website also has many blogposts in words only.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know how to explain this. I am a native speaker, but I don’t get it. 稿件投诉， it doesn’t seem to make sense to me. It can mean a couple of things or nothing. I usually see 稿件投递 or 客户投诉。

From the website, [BIBI](https://www.bilibili.com/appeal/?avid=67558778) it has the following explanation,

你觉得这个稿件有什么问题? 违法违禁, 色情, 低俗, 赌博诈骗, etc.

Therefore, according to the author, 稿件投诉 means 对本网站上采用的稿件的投诉. (Reporting the manuscripts of our website that may not be appropriate for the public or offensive to you.)

But I still prefer 违规投诉 or 内容投诉.

In general, this is a typical word formation method using a VO structure but in a reversed order. For example,

节目预告, catalog of the performance

产品说明, product manual

操作指南, operation guide

救灾指挥部, the center for disaster relief

图书促销日, book sale day

In English, if you can find a noun for the verb, you do not need a VO structure.

Some words are SV structure, For example,

客户投诉, customer complains

旅客休息室, traveler sitting room

Comment: 没事，我身边也学了那么多时间，但也很多矛盾，谢谢

Comment: 是的。汉语很灵活，以至于有的时候，有些语句没有明确的意思。Indeed, Chinese is so flexible that sometimes some sentences do not have a definitive meaning.

Comment: I added more examples to help to illustrate the answer. Thanks.

Comment: 没事，好详细，非常感谢您的描述和例子。